# Logging raw queries Generated by MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, logging, mongoengine

I need to log all the queries generated by MongoEngine in my Django app.

I cannot use `cursor._query()` as I need to log queries for all the MongoEngine Documents.

The logging should be done at app level and not DB level so setting MongoDB profiling level to 2 will not help.

I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kesor/1589672), which seems helpful but I fail to understand it.

Is there a simpler way to write a middleware or any other way I can log all the queries.

Comment: Did you manage to log the queries? I'm having the same problem now.

Answer (score 4):

I used `pymongo.monitoring` in my project.

```
import logging
from pymongo import monitoring

class CommandLogger(monitoring.CommandListener):

    def started(self, event):
        log.debug("Command {0.command}".format(event))
        logging.info("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                 "{0.request_id} started on server "
                 "{0.connection_id}".format(event))

    def succeeded(self, event):
        logging.info("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                 "{0.request_id} on server {0.connection_id} "
                 "succeeded in {0.duration_micros} "
                 "microseconds".format(event))

    def failed(self, event):
        logging.info("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                 "{0.request_id} on server {0.connection_id} "
                 "failed in {0.duration_micros} "
                 "microseconds".format(event))

monitoring.register(CommandLogger())
```

More detailed see:

- [pymongo documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/monitoring.html)
- info about [profiler](https://flask-mongo-profiler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: Woaw! That's awesome, Thanks!